# How do I allow a port?

Tags: windows-7, firewall

I am trying to use a speaker share program called "SpeakerShare". What it does is to share a speaker. I have a speaker on my desktop. I would like to use the desktop speaker from my laptop. When I try to use SpeakerShare, it says that it can't connect to server. I asked the author of the program and got reply from him:

> This is a network related error. There must be something blocking 
>   packets from client, maybe it's your router. Or maybe another instance 
>   is running on the server computer. That's all I can say for now. I 
>   tested on two machines Windows 7 installed without problem. Can you 
>   post here if you make it work?

I am using windows 7 on both laptop and desktop. I disabled firewall completely, but I still can't connect.

Is there any other software that I should disable?

Comment: Like mentioned from the given answer, it could be from your router. What do you use as a router, to connect between your laptop and desktop computers? It could be filtered by it as well.

Comment: @Gnoupi // I disabled everything. This is very weird..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure if this is linked to your router, or only to computers, you could try to connect directly the two computers, without a router in the middle.

This way, you would be sure if the router is the cause or not.

You can find a tutorial [here](http://www.labnol.org/software/connect-computers-without-router/11049/), if needed.

Comment: Good point, but just in case: isn't the Windows firewall configured per network? And if so: doesn't the above create some new additional network, hence with its own firewall settings?

Comment: According to his question, he deactivated Windows Firewall completely, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Obviously the problem was on the router side, if that was accepted.